# zip files in zip file missing when unzip it in linux

Tags: linux, zip, virtualbox, unzip

I have a virtualbox hosted on win10, guest operate system is ubuntu22.04. I fond share folder from win10 do not extract zip files in zip file.

Say a zip file (a.zip) which contains another zip content (b.zip) inside it.

When I unzip it from windows10, it works fine. but when I unzip it (a.zip) in ubuntu22.04 from a share folder, the b.zip file is missing.

```
diff -qr a_linux a_win10
b.zip
```

The command to unzip:

```
unzip a.zip -d a_linux
```

But if unzip it under home folder, (not the share folder from win10), it works fine.

Comment: Do you have permission to write to directory `a_linux` ?

Comment: Yes, other non-zip files extracted correctly. Only the b.zip file is missing.

Comment: have you try `cd a_linux; unzip ../a.zip`?